# Autohotkey: end a loop by pressing a certain shortcut

Tags: loops, autohotkey

I searched a lot on the site but did not find how to do it.
This is my current script:

```
MButton::
  MouseGetPos, xpos, ypos
  Sleep, 50
  Click
  Loop
  {
    Sleep 50
    Send, {\ down}
    Sleep 50
    Send, {\ up}
  }
  Click %xpos%, %ypos%, 0
Return
```

I would like to end the loop by pressing the middle button of the mouse (MButton).
I think is not a difficult task but cannot find it out, can you help thanks very much

EDIT so the code posted by @Jim U, and @user3419297 works very well! Code by GroggyOtter gives error when I run it. Code by Forivin seems to work in another way (explained below).
Thank you so much to all of you!

EDIT 2 an even more easy code

```
MButton::
MouseGetPos, xpos, ypos
Sleep, 50
Click
Loop
{
    Sleep 50
    Send, {\ down}
    Sleep 50
    Send, {\ up}
    If GetKeyState("MButton", "P") AND (A_TimeSinceThisHotkey > 300)    ; When the MButton is pressed and after 300ms have elapsed(to prevent it from stopping direcly after triggering it.
        Break
}
Click %xpos%, %ypos%, 0
Return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This starts and interrupts a loop when MButton is pressed**

```
#MaxThreadsPerHotkey 2

MButton::mbutton_pressed()

mbutton_pressed()
{
  global running := !running

  if running
    run()
}


run()
{
  global running

  MouseGetPos, xpos, ypos
  Sleep, 50
  Click

  while running
  {
    Sleep 50
    Send, {\ down}
    Sleep 50
    Send, {\ up}
  }
  Click %xpos%, %ypos%, 0
}
```

`#MaxThreadsPerHotkey 2` allows us to invoke MButton even if the previous invocation of MButton hasn't completed.  This allows us to use MButton to both start and interrupt the loop.

Answer (score 1):

All it should take is adding a toggle. Use a variable to track on and off status and use the command [`SetTimer`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm) to control your loop.

```
; Set to 0 by default so when we press the button the first time
; it executes the if statement first.
toggle  := 0
return

MButton::
    toggle  := !toggle  ; This is the variable that tracks on/off for your loop.
                        ; 1 becomes 0. 0 Becomes 1. It's updated as soon as the hotkey fires.

    if (toggle = 1){    ; If toggle is 1, do this stuff.
        MouseGetPos, xpos, ypos
        Sleep, 50
        Click
        SetTimer, BackslashLoop, 50 ; Runs the BackslashLoop label over and over until it's turned off
                                    ; To turn it off, press MButton again.
    }else{ ; Only do this stuff after MButton has been clicked again and toggle has been changed.
        SetTimer, BackslashLoop, Off
        Click %xpos%, %ypos%, 0
    }
return

BackslashLoop:
        Send, {\ down}
        Sleep 50
        Send, {\ up}    
return
```

If this fixed your problem, please mark this answered.
If not, let us know what isn't working so we can figure out what's up.

Comment: `SetTimer, toggleLabel, Off` should be `SetTimer, BackslashLoop, Off`.

Comment: thank you so much, but when I run it, this error appears http://i.imgur.com/nl3HIVO.png

Comment: That was leftover code. I use a hotstring to make toggles and toggleLabel is the default variable I use. Like user3419297 said, it should be BackslashLoop. I just missed changing it when I was writing this :P Post has been updated. Edit: [So you can see what I mean :P](http://i.imgur.com/UxdKgrt.gifv)

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be this:

```
#If !mbuttonIsRunning ;Only enable this hotkey when it is not running
    MButton Up:: ;When the MButton is pressed
        mbuttonIsRunning := True 
        MouseGetPos, xpos, ypos
        Sleep, 50
        Click
        Loop
        {
            Sleep 50
            Send, {\ down}
            Sleep 50
            Send, {\ up}
            If GetKeyState("MButton", "P") ;If MButton is pressed
                Break ;Break out of the loop
        }
        Click %xpos%, %ypos%, 0
        mbuttonIsRunning := False
    Return
#If
```

Comment: thank you so much, but this works in another way: when I hold the Mbutton the script pause, and when I release the Mbutton the script resumes. It seems like Mbutton works like a pause button.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach (based on Forivin's code):

```
; autoexecute-section (top of the script):
loop_enabled := false ; the loop is disabled by default

; Press MButton down to enable the loop
MButton:: loop_enabled := true

#If (loop_enabled) ; If you enable the loop by pressing MButton down

    MButton Up::  ; release MButton to start the loop
        MouseGetPos, xpos, ypos
        Sleep, 50
        Click
        Loop
        {
            Sleep 50
            Send, {\ down}
            Sleep 50
            Send, {\ up}
            If GetKeyState("MButton", "P") ; by pressing MButton while the loop is enabled
            {
                loop_enabled := false      ; disable and
                    break                  ; terminate the loop
            }
        }
        Click %xpos%, %ypos%, 0 
    Return

#If
```